# plt.scatter of 2-d array elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I have a list containing array elements:

```
[array([2.40460915, 0.85513601]), array([1.80998096, 0.97406986]), array([2.14505475, 0.96109123]), 
array([2.12467111, 0.93991277])]
```

And I want to plot that list using mathplotlib, such that i iterate over each element in the list, and plot the `ith` element, using `plt.scatter(x,y)` where x is the first element of the array at the `ith` position, and similar for y the second element.

I am not super familiar with how to do this indexing in python, and no matter how I try to solve this, I cannot get a plot.

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    # plt.scatter(x,y) for x,y as described above
```

Can anyone tell me an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please don't shadow builtin names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip` the `unpacked values` of numpy array `a`.

One-liner to plot as you want:

```
plt.scatter(*zip(*a))
```

which is equivalent to `x,y=zip(*a); plt.scatter(x,y)`

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=[np.array([2.40460915, 0.85513601]), np.array([1.80998096, 0.97406986]), np.array([2.14505475, 0.96109123]), np.array([2.12467111, 0.93991277])]
plt.scatter(*zip(*a)) #x,y=zip(*a)
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [array([2.40460915, 0.85513601]), array([1.80998096, 0.97406986]), array([2.14505475, 0.96109123]), 
array([2.12467111, 0.93991277])]

# *i unpacks i into a tuple (i[0], i[1]), which is interpreted as (x,y) by plt.scatter
for i in a:
    plt.scatter(*i)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe you can use better names and unpack sooner:  `XYs = [...]` and later `for x, y in XYs: plt.scatter(x, y)`

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a= [np.array([2.40460915, 0.85513601]), 
    np.array([1.80998096, 0.97406986]),
    np.array([2.14505475, 0.96109123]),
    np.array([2.12467111, 0.93991277])]

plt.scatter([i[0] for i in a], [i[1] for i in a])  # just this line here
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this question. I write two that you will understand easily:

Solution 1: many scatters

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    point = data[i] #the element ith in data
    x = point[0] #the first coordenate of the point, x
    y = point[1] #the second coordenate of the point, y
    plt.scatter(x,y) #plot the point
plt.show()
```

Solution 2: one scatter (I recomend if you are not familiarizated with indexing)

```
x = []
y = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    point = data[i]
    x.append(point[0])
    y.append(point[1])
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The solution of @NicolasGervais is shorter than the others, but if you are not familiarizated with indexing, it can be difficult to understand at first

Answer (score -1):

try converting the array into pandas Dataframe by

```
data=pd.DataFrame(data='''array''')
```

and try plotting the datas